# Openstreetmap Xapi filters

Tags: openstreetmap

Is there anyway to filter the results returned using xapi so that I don't have a ton of results to work through? I thought something like [filter=tag] might only show tags but I can't seem to find any documentation saying this is possible.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(1) The standard way of using XAPI lets you filter to retrieve only objects tagged with a certain tag, for example just to get pubs you'd use:

```
http://jxapi.osm.rambler.ru/xapi/api/0.6/*[amenity=pub]
```

(2) If you want to filter an OSM file after you've downloaded it (e.g. to remove certain tags), [Osmosis](http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Osmosis) is a command-line tool that can do various types of filtering.

(3) If you want to filter an OSM file into some other format (i.e. you're not interested in having an OSM-format XML file at the end) you could use XSLT. [Here is an XSLT I made](https://github.com/danstowell/pubdensity/blob/master/osm_pub_csv.xslt) which extracts a small number of pub parameters from an OSM file to CSV.

Comment: If you need to specify more than a single filter you have to use the [Overpass API](https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Overpass_API) which is way more flexible than the XAPI.

Comment: do you know of anything like osmosis for php?